# VBA: Determining Date Based on Workbook Name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that gets sent out every month with the name `MONTH YEAR Report` (e.g. `January 2016 Report`)

The report has all the necessary information within the worksheet with the exception of the month and year. Is there a way to pull the month and year based on the name of the workbook to a column?

Comment: In vba you would use the Left() and Instr() function.

Comment: `sFileName = Format(Month(Date),"mmmm") & " " & Format(Year(Date,"yyyy") & " Report"` or `sFileName = Format(Month(Date),"mmmm") & " " & Format(Year(Date,"yyyy") & " " & Range("A1").Value2 & " "  Range("A2").Value2` if there is specific naming details stored in ranges.

Comment: for a non-vba solution that you can place right into a cell see the `=Cell("filename",A1)`. This will return the full path of the file, which you can extract using `Find, Mid, Left, etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this irregardless of the name structure

```
Sub GetMonthAndYear()
    Dim i As Integer, yr As Integer
    Dim na As String, mnth As String
    Dim arr

    na = ThisWorkbook.Name

    For i = 1 To 12
        If InStr(1, na, MonthName(i, True)) > 0 Then
            mnth = MonthName(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    arr = Split(na, " ")

    On Error Resume Next
    yr = Join(Filter(arr, 19), "")
    yr = Join(Filter(arr, 20), "")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If yr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find year of report for " & na
    Else
        MsgBox "Month of report is: " & mnth & vbNewLine & "Year of report is: " & yr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer worked the best for my purposes, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get the month and year from the given filename if the format of the filename is maintained.

```
 Sub MonAndYear()
    Dim MyNAme As String
    Dim Cet 
    MyName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Cet =Split(MyName," ")
    Dim Mon As String
    Dim Yr As String
    Mon = Cet(0)
    Yr = Cet(1)

     MsgBox "Month is " & Cet(0)
     MsgBox "Year is " & Cet(1)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have this formula put into the workbook which gets carried forward monthly:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",B1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",B1))+1,FIND(".xls",CELL("filename",B1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",B1))-1)
```

This looks at the workbook's own filename, and pulls every character in between the "[" & "]" brackets. That is, it doesn't include the filepath and sheet name.